Can you specify expectations in mocked class constructor in GMock?
I want to create a Mock Class that will have some default characteristics on its mocked methods ie:
struct SuperMock {
  SuperMock() {
    ON_CALL(*this, mockedMethod1).WillByDefault(Return(1));
    ON_CALL(*this, mockedMethod2).WillByDefault(Return(2));
  }
  MOCK_CONST_METHOD(mockedMethod1, int());
  MOCK_CONST_METHOD(mockedMethod2, int());
};

Is that legal? Will it work properly?

Yes, you can do it.

Yes, you can do that. See such usage in the example on the official guide page:


class MockFoo : public Foo {
 public:
  MockFoo() {
    // By default, all calls are delegated to the real object.
    ON_CALL(*this, DoThis).WillByDefault([this](int n) {
      return real_.DoThis(n);
    });
    ON_CALL(*this, DoThat).WillByDefault([this](const char* s, int* p) {
      real_.DoThat(s, p);
    });
    ...
  }
  MOCK_METHOD(char, DoThis, ...);
  MOCK_METHOD(void, DoThat, ...);
  ...
 private:
  Foo real_;
};


